# htaccess redirect old subfolders to non subfolders

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have an old site with urls A and B

```
A. www.site.com/about
B. www.site.com/about/subpage
```

I need to redirect

```
A. www.site.com/about-us
B. www.site.com/not-a-sub-anymore
```

My htaccess contains

```
Redirect 301 /about /about-us
Redirect 301 /about/subpage /not-a-sub-anymore
```

The first redirect works fine, however, my second redirect seems to inherit the first rule resulting in redirecting me to `www.site.com/about-us/not-a-sub-anymore` which results in a 404 obviously. How can I work around this issue?

**edit:** I am using apache2.2.3 and I see in apache 2.4.8 they've added a `RewriteRule IgnoreInherit` which seems like something I'd be looking for. I have no control of my version of apache unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest redirecting via RewriteRule to prevent additional rules from firing:

```
RewriteRule ^about/subpage$     /not-a-sub-anymore  [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^about$             /about-us           [R=301,L]
```

However, if you insist on using Redirect 301, I'd try rearranging the order:

```
Redirect 301 /about/subpage /not-a-sub-anymore
Redirect 301 /about         /about-us
```